# Find the mass of $S$. (Any tricks to make this shorter?)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

> Find the mass of the surface: $S=\{(x,y,z)| x^2+y^2\le 2x, z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \}$. 
> With mass density: $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$.

So from the question I understand that I need to calculate $\iint_Sf(x,y,z)dS$. 
What I did was I took this parametrization: $\vec S(t,r)=(1+r\cos(t), r\sin(t), r)$. 
And found the normal vector length $|\vec S_r\times \vec S_t|$ and started calculating the integral with so much variables and alot of space to make lots of mistakes, and I got stuck integrating. 
I want to know if there's any other hidden ways to solve this integral, I really wanted to use gauss/stokes theorems, but it doesn't work in this type of integral, but I'm positive there's something I'm missing that could've made this easier. 
Any ideas and help is really appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you really mean to write $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, I guess it's the cone itself, bounded above by the circle $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$

Comment: Then the mass is $0$, right? Since it is a surface.

Comment: Do you think the parametrization is fine? I'd set x = $r \cos(t)$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The final answer is $3\sqrt{2} \pi$, I was too surprised when faced this question, I was never asked to calculate the mass of a surface like this.

Comment: You should accept the fact that its either $z\leqslant\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ or $z\geqslant\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I checked it a couple of times and it's equal, and if it was $z\le$ then it wouldn't say find the mass of the surface.. (That's what it says in the original question before me translating, I'll add it). So I'm not really sure..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are integrating over the surface of the cone, parametrize the surface as,

$r(\rho, t) = (\rho \cos t, \rho \sin t, \rho)$

$|r_{\rho} \times r_t| = \rho \sqrt2$

Now note that $x^2 + y^2 \leq 2x \implies \rho \leq 2 \cos t, -\frac{\pi}{2} \leq t \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

So the integral is,

$\displaystyle \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{2\cos t} \rho \sqrt2 \ (2 \rho^2) \ d\rho \ dt = 3 \sqrt2 \pi$

Comment: Thanks alot again! Could you explain the intuition of picking this parametrization? And why my parametrization is bad this time? I've always been going with finding the shadow on the $x,y$ plane and parametrize according to that, why this time it's better to parametrize according to the cone?

Comment: @Pwaol this is surface integral so we need to see which surface we are integrating over. As we are integrating over cone's surface which is $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, parametrization using $r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta$ is a natural preference. But we then check what it does to the condition given on $x, y$, which is $x^2 + y^2 \leq 2x$ which gives us $r \leq 2\cos\theta$ and that works.

Comment: I see, It's a little hard for me to grasp because we're actually inside a circle on the cone, so I imagined the angle to be from zero to $2\pi$, but I guess when parametrizing a surface, I should care on the surface only? And one more thing, if $x^2+y^2 \le 2x$ that means $r^2 \le 2\cos(t)$, is that a mistake? and how do I deal with it with square roots?

Comment: yes we first care for the surface and then check the condition. Say the cylinder was not this nice and it was instead $(x-2)^2 + (y-2)^2 \leq 1$, I would then rethink the strategy and probably not go with what we did here as the condition on $x, y$ becomes tricky.

Comment: $x^2 + y^2 \leq 2x \implies r^2 \leq 2 r \cos\theta \implies r \leq 2 \cos\theta$